# SQL query to determine if events happen out of chronological order

Tags: sql, hive, avro

I'm new to SQL. I'm trying to write a query that would tell me if some events were happening earlier than the first event (i.e. for each ID, firstEvent time should come first, then secondEvent time, etc.).

Each event is an object and the time is AVRO type timestamp (in the actual Java code, it's an Instant). This is the query so far, but it's only yielding blank cells:

```sql
select * from ( 
    select * from (
        select t.id as id,
            t.firstEvent.time as firstTime,
            t.secondEvent.time as secondTime,
            t.thirdEvent.time as thirdTime,
            t.fourthEvent.time as fourthTime,
        from avroTable t
        where t.firstEvent.time is not null
        ) allTimesT
    where (
        allTimesT.firstTime > allTimesT.secondTime 
        or allTimesT.firstTime > allTimesT.thirdTime
        or allTimesT.firstTime > allTimesT.fourthTime
    )
) finalT
```

The query works if I just look for firstEvent times that are not null, but once I hit the `where...or` block, it's just giving me blanks.

I was wondering if there just wasn't any data that matched these criteria, so I tried switching the operator and doing `allTimesT.firstTime < allTimesT.secondTime` (the expected case), but that also gave me blank cells. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Here's some sample data:
[image: Sample data]

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Can the various Time columns have nulls in them? If they can then you probably need to explicitly allow for this in your code

Comment: @HoneyBadger Just added it. This is for work, so it's not real data, but it's in the same format

Comment: @NickW yes, a lot of the columns have null time values

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? I don't know Hive so you might have to tweak a bit:

```
with data as (
    select t.id as id,
        coalesce(t.firstEvent.time, t.secondEvent.time, t.thirdEvent.time, t.fourthEvent.time, '99991231') as time1,
        coalesce(t.secondEvent.time, t.thirdEvent.time, t.fourthEvent.time, '99991231') as time2,
        coalesce(t.thirdEvent.time, t.fourthEvent.time, '99991231') as time3,
        coalesce(t.fourthEvent.time. '99991231') as time4
    from avroTable t
)
select *
from data
where time1 > time2 or time2 > time3 or time3 > time4;
where
```